# (LARAVEL) HasManyThrough relation causing to exceed "Allowed memory size"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination, relational-database

To keep it simple, let's take an example of [stackoverflow's questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) where there is a paginated list of questions and each question has some tags attached to it.

A **Tag** model is in Many to Many relation with **Question** model i.e.

- A tag can be assigned to many questions.
- A question can be assigned to many tags.

For this relation I created an relational model named **QuestionTag** (and table for it) that has the relation with both Tag and Question. Then I used laravel's `hasManyThrough` relation to get a list of tags assigned to a question through the  `QuestionTag` model as such:

```php
class QuestionTag extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'question_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class, 'tag_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Question extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, QuestionTag::class, 'question_id', 'id', 'id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

And I created **QuestionResource** for returning the expected paginated results of questions as such:

**QuestionResource**

```
class QuestionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'subject' => $this->subject,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'tags' => $this->tags // this will call the has many through relations as expected.
        ];
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "subject": "Lorem ipsum dolor sir amet!",
            "body": "...",
            tags: [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "tag1",
                },
                // ...and so on
            ]
        },
        // ...and so on
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uv1/questions?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uv1/questions?page=1",
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uv1/questions",
    "per_page": "15",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 5,
    "total": 5
}
```

At last, on the index function, I returned the paginated list of questions from the `QuestionController's index function` as such:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $perPage = $request->input('perPage') ?? 15;
    // execute the query.
    $crawlers = Question::paginate($perPage);

    return QuestionResource::collection($crawlers);
}
```

It returned what I wanted but when I increased the per_page size to **100** or **more**, it is returning this error:

**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)**

I found many solutions that suggests to increase the memory in php.ini(`memory_limit = 2048M`) but it feels like we are bruteforcing to acheive the outcome. There will be some point when again the memory_limit will fail to return the same when I keep on increasing the per_page size.

Is there any **optimal way in laravel** to get the same expected result(instead of above mentioned error) with the desired output without increasing the memory size?

Comment: did u restart your apache server after modifying php.ini file?

Comment: Please read through the last paragraph. I've mentioned that `It is a feasible option but don't want to increase the memory_limit` as I am searching any **optimal way in Laravel** if any for solving this.

Comment: "A Tag model is in Many to Many relation with Question model" <- No need for hasManyThrough here. Both of those models should have method that returns `belongsToMany`. It's just `Question::find(1)->tags` or `Question::find(1)->tags()->first()`. Side note, if you are creating pivot model it should extends Pivot class. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't solve the issue. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used **Inner Join** to achieve this and used MySQL's `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT())` along with it in `SELECT` statement to create a concatenated json string of tags and later convert it to json array using php `json_decode()`. Little tacky but it returned the result fast and I could load thousands of records within milliseconds.

My **QuestionController** now looks like this:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $perPage = $request->input('perPage') ?? 15;
    // execute the query.
    $crawlers = Question::query()
    ->select(['questions.*', DB::raw('JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id", `tags`.`id`, "name", `tags`.`name`)) AS `tags`')])
    ->join('question_tags', 'questions.id', 'question_tags.question_id')
    ->join('tags', 'question_tags.tag_id', 'tags.id')
    ->groupBy('questions.id')
    ->paginate($perPage);

    return QuestionResource::collection($crawlers);
}
```

And I removed the join relations from the models and changed my **QuestionResource** as such:

```php
class QuestionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'subject' => $this->subject,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'tags' => json_decode($this->tags ?? '[]', false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR), // convert string JSON to array
        ];
    }
}
```

Currently, I've implemented this approach but  **I'm still open to better solutions. :)**